# conjur python api thorwing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am using conjur-client==0.1.0 and conjur==0.4.4, python 3.8. The exception message looks like

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conjur/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from config import Config
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

So far I tried changing python version to 3.7, conjur version to older versions but have no success.
What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't install both `conjur` and `conjur-client` on Python 3.

Based on https://pypi.org/project/Conjur/ :

> If you are looking for Python3 API client, please go to our new project page at https://github.com/cyberark/conjur-api-python3.
>
> IMPORTANT: THIS API CLIENT IS NOT CURRENTLY ACTIVELY BEING SUPPORTED

The Python 3 client is just `conjur-client`. https://pypi.org/project/conjur-client/